# Segmentation fault after running vectore based forwarding protocol in aqua-sim

Tags: networking, tcl, ns2

can someone please help me trace this error, i'm using vector based forwarding protocol tcl example on 400 nodes and i got this error

```
UWSink (id:0): I get the packet data no.0 from 378 
SK 0: Num_Recv 412, InterArrival 0.298128
UWSink (id:0): I get the packet data no.11 from 262 
SK 0: Num_Recv 413, InterArrival 0.057902
UWSink (id:0): I get the packet data no.4 from 79 
SK 0: Num_Recv 414, InterArrival 0.368108
UWSink (id:0): I get the packet data no.10 from 79 
SK 0: Num_Recv 415, InterArrival 0.741583
UWSink (id:0): I get the packet data no.4 from 262 
SK 0: Num_Recv 416, InterArrival 0.216878

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000060871c in TclRegisterLiteral ()
```

Comment: Looks like memory corruption. It's probably in your code (perhaps wrong reference count management) but the resulting corruption triggered a crash in the core of Tcl. Debugging suggestion: enable memory debugging in the build of Tcl (`configure --enable-symbols=mem`) and see if that helps narrow it down.

Comment: About 'Segmentation fault' ns2 https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ns2-and-aqua-sim-4175507630/#3

Answer (score 0):

Also ref. your other AquaSim VBF thread, with the most of a simulation file : [VBFP doesnt work probably in aqua-sim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123945/vbfp-doesnt-work-probably-in-aqua-sim)

... node 4 - 398 are missing. I filled in some node settings, 4 - 85 by a random external file : `source 82-nodePositions` . I will suggest that you upload the complete simulation file.tcl to e.g. Dropbox, and post a **shared** link.

*Your errors* : Old ns2 code like AquaSim can crash with a late glibc / libc6, 
e.g. Ubuntu 17.xx .

I made the tests with three 'Linux OS' : PCLinuxOS 2017 - 64, Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64, CentOS 6.9 - i386.

Example result, CentOS 6.9 - 32 :

```
$ ns-aqua-el6 A.Moh-VBF-n400.tcl

the file name is test.data
the sending interval is 10.0
num_nodes is set 401
Width=100
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
Node 400 is sending first!!
starting Simulation...
GOD: the old file name istest.data
GOD: the new file name istest.data
SINK 0 : terminates (send 0, recv 0, cum_delay 0.000000)
god: the energy consumped is 16681.600000
NS EXISTING...
```

The trace file `test.tr` is OK. 92.4 .. 96.8 MB. The nam trace `test.nam` has no
"trace lines" : Indicates that some nam settings are missing in the simulation file.tcl . Or caused by my random node settings.

The complete results https://www.dropbox.com/s/fov2r82s88rfhaq/A.Moh-Nov12-result2.tar.gz?dl=0

---

EDIT : Ref. your comment #2 : Got your new example, "VBF 401 nodes". Tested with PCLinuxOS 2017, CentOS 7.4, Ubuntu 16.04, CentOS 6.9 - 64, and the 32bits CentOS 6.9 → The two usable results can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl6pnyz3cdklu5g/VBF_example_5-n401-result.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: first, thank you very much for your effort and time,

Comment: Regarding my previous thread, i manged to solve my problem and i succeed to make one node to send the packets, however, in this example i want  all nodes to send packets periodically to test the lifetime of the network, this is my tcl file https://www.dropbox.com/s/06bbpgwleabll2i/vbf_example_5.tcl?dl=0

Comment: Your `VBF_example_5-n401.tcl` (The file name vbf_example_5.tcl is already used, see aquasim-examples-09.17.tar.gz) ... works with PCLinuxOS2017 and the 32bits CentOS 6.9 → https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl6pnyz3cdklu5g/VBF_example_5-n401-result.tar.gz?dl=0 ... Ubuntu: No luck → Segmentation fault.